# Is it possible modify Chakra UI's rem size?

Tags: chakra-ui

Pretty much the title. Have searched on docs for instructions on how to do that but had no luck.

My setup is using NextJS and resetCSS is being passed through ChakraProvider so I can't change the  style to modify font-size because Chakra will overwrite that.

Answer (score 7):

I have asked for help on reddit as well and someone guided me to [this part](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/global-styles) of docs that let me work this out.

So, at _app.js I have theme const that extendsTheme. Just added

```
styles: { 
  global: { 
      html: { 
          fontSize: "18px"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it is possible. For example, I want to make sm font size to be larger:

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react"

const theme = extendTheme({
  ...
  fontSizes: {
    sm: "1.4rem",
  },
  ...
})
```